# Last column not displayed MS Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I am displaying a column type chart on my Asp.net page. The code is as follows :

```
private DataSet FetchDummyChartData()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));
        table.Rows.Add("FRA", "Completed", 20);
        table.Rows.Add("FRA", "Exceptions", 10);
        table.Rows.Add("Swaption", "Exceptions", 15);
        table.Rows.Add("Swaption", "Completed", 50);
        table.Rows.Add("Cap/Floor", "Exceptions", 40);
        table.Rows.Add("Cap/Floor", "Approval Pending", 10);
        table.Rows.Add("Single currency swap", "Completed", 70);
        table.Rows.Add("Single currency swap", "Approval Pending", 30);
        table.Rows.Add("Cross currency swap", "Completed", 60);
        table.Rows.Add("Cross currency swap", "Exceptions", 20);
        table.Rows.Add("IRS", "Completed", 40);
        table.Rows.Add("IRS", "Approval Pending", 70);
        table.Rows.Add("Single currency Option", "Completed", 70);
        table.Rows.Add("Single currency Option", "Exceptions", 50);
        table.Rows.Add("Some Derivative", "Completed", 40);
        table.Rows.Add("Some Derivative", "Exceptions", 10);
        table.Rows.Add("Some Derivative", "Approval Pending", 50);
        ds.Tables.Add(table);

        return ds;
    }
 Chart2.DataBindCrossTable(new DataView(FetchDummyChartData().Tables[0]), "Status", "Product", "Count", null);
```

The problem is that if items on X-axis contains larger than 3-4 items, (Here the items "FRA", "IRS" etc represents the X-axis) then the last columns aren't displayed. Note that this is a multiline chart. This is very wierd behaviour. There is no CSS/space issue, I checked that.

Here is the screenshot :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are grouping the data with `Status` but you don't have `Status` values for each `Product` on the `X axis`.  So there are `EmptyPoints` in the series. Now you could use

```
Chart2.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Days, "series name");
```

but the `IntervalType` is an `enum` predfined with `Number`, `Years`, `Months` etc. but our `IntervalType` should be `Status`. I haven't checked if it is possible to define custom `IntervalType`, so the best bet is to check the table for missing `Status` entries for each `Product` in the  `DataTable` and fill them with a default value, then the chart will display correctly.

```
table.Rows.Add("FRA", "Completed", 20);
table.Rows.Add("FRA", "Exceptions", 10);
table.Rows.Add("FRA", "Approval Pending", 0);

table.Rows.Add("Swaption", "Exceptions", 15);
table.Rows.Add("Swaption", "Completed", 50);
table.Rows.Add("Swaption", "Approval Pending", 0);

table.Rows.Add("Cap/Floor", "Exceptions", 40);
table.Rows.Add("Cap/Floor", "Approval Pending", 10);
table.Rows.Add("Cap/Floor", "Completed", 0);

table.Rows.Add("Single currency swap", "Completed", 70);
table.Rows.Add("Single currency swap", "Approval Pending", 30);
table.Rows.Add("Single currency swap", "Exceptions", 0);

table.Rows.Add("Cross currency swap", "Exceptions", 20);
table.Rows.Add("Cross currency swap", "Completed", 0);
table.Rows.Add("Cross currency swap", "Approval Pending", 0);

table.Rows.Add("IRS", "Completed", 40);
table.Rows.Add("IRS", "Approval Pending", 70);
table.Rows.Add("IRS", "Exceptions", 0);

table.Rows.Add("Single currency Option", "Completed", 70);
table.Rows.Add("Single currency Option", "Exceptions", 50);
table.Rows.Add("Single currency Option", "Approval Pending", 0);

table.Rows.Add("Some Derivative", "Completed", 40);
table.Rows.Add("Some Derivative", "Exceptions", 10);
table.Rows.Add("Some Derivative", "Approval Pending", 50);
```

Comment: Absolutely, Thanks a lot for the answer. Though I was able to figure that out myself, but it kept me frustrated for a long time.